# Udp packets dropped starting with specific size

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

I wrote a custom application in c# that sends data to a remote computer. However if I send more than 23672 bytes at once, the data won't arrive (~99% packet drop). When opening up Wireshark, i found this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Uu3.jpg)
It looks like the udp packet fragmentation fails, which is really strange because a packet of 23672 or lower will also get fragmented.

When testing the same application localhost everything works fine up to 65507 bytes (udp header limit). Test application that reproduces the error:

```
        var client = new UdpClient();
        var sequenceNumber = 0; //i'm sending a sequence number to determine how many packets i've lost
        while (true)
        {

            var buffer = new byte[23673];
            BitConverter.GetBytes(sequenceNumber++).CopyTo(buffer, 0);
            client.Client.SendTo(buffer, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 1234));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

How can i resolve this issue? 
Or should i just make my packets smaller? If yes, whats the best packet size for sending udp data over the internet?

Comment: Please insert images into the question to maintain availability.

Comment: Does it always fail at the same spot?  When a packet get fragmented each datagram may get routed differently.  It is recombined at the receiving end.  if you are getting errors it may indicated a hardware issue (bad router or Ethernet cable).  It would start by using PING using some of the options to determine if there is hardware issue.  Open a cmd.exe and type Ping/? to see different option.  Send large data packets and check if you are getting any errors.

Comment: Why aren't you using TCP? Why aren't you creating the endpoint outside the loop? Also, your test prog is sending the number of bytes which you are claiming to work.

Comment: @jdweng I doubt that there are many different routes from bis computer to bis 192.168.1.100. It's very likely the same subnet. And there won't be hardware issues as smaller packets are going thru. Might be a router issue or related to your NIC driver though.

Comment: @Tobias Knauss I can't include the image because i'm a new user ...
And yes, this example is working. If i change the byte array size to 23673 and it won't work for me. @ jdweng I'll try to use a different router, thanks for the idea

Comment: Tobias : Don't assume just because the two addresses are in the same network there aren't routes in the path or multiple paths.  I've seen issue like this with hardware issue with small error rates.  The question that need to me answered does it always work with 23672 and doesn't work with 23673.  We have a large building at work with 1000 different computers.  We have DCHP enabled.  We probably have 30 to 50 routers in network.  Computers within same subnet could be in opposite sides of the building going through a different set of routers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your Screenshot, I think it's hardware (NIC of switch) or driver related. The input buffer might be too small to store all fragments of that packet and therefore time out when trying to reassemble it.
Localhost is different, afaik it does not even touch the NIC.
Use TCP and/or smaller packets.

Comment: Thank you! Do you recommend using a specific packet size?

Comment: I would split the data by myself to avoid fragmentation. Check out TCP MTU (usually around 1500, like 1470) or UDP MTU (I just found values like 512; search for 'UDP max packet size')